# Why can't I create a Windows backup on my secondary disk?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I've installed Windows 7 Ultimate on an SSD that I've added to the XPS desktop that I bought from Dell. I would like to use the built-in backup functionality to create incremental backups and store them on the large drive that came with the machine.  I formatted the large drive and turned it into a Basic disk.

However, when I try to set the backup location to the large internal disk (E:\) in the "Set up backup" wizard, a get a message saying, "A system image cannot be saved on a drive that your computer boots from or that Windows is installed on."

Windows is *not* installed on that disk.  I even deleted the OEM partition that was on the disk, and removed it completely from the boot order in the BIOS.

Any clue why Windows is griping at me about this?

Answer (score 1):

Your system drive does not have to be the same drive as windows is installed on. So it would look like your machine is starting off the harddrive (which tells it to continue booting off the SSD)

Try reading [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchingMyWindows7BootDiskFromDToCWithBCDBootRatherThanBCDEdit.aspx) following article which describes (better than I can) a similar problem and a resolution.