# Windows - Unable to select target disk for Backup - Disk is a bootable drive

Tags: windows-10, backup

I have a Windows 10 system and I'm trying to do a System Image backup, but I'm unable to select my secondary volume with an error "A system image cannot be saved on a drive that your computer boots from or that Windows is installed on".

This disk is not my boot disk (confirmed with Disk Management Utility, "Basic Data Partition") and does NOT have an install of Windows on it.

How can I tell Windows that this disk *isn't* a bootable target so I can select it for as a backup destination? This is also preventing File History from allowing me to select this disk.  The disk is formatted GPT, so I can't use diskpart to mark it inactive.

This is NOT a duplicate of [Why can't I create a Windows backup on my secondary disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/133752/why-cant-i-create-a-windows-backup-on-my-secondary-disk). My primary disk and boot volume is correctly assigned as my 250GB SSD, not my secondary 4TB disk.

Comment: One possibility is to mark the disk as "Inactive" using diskpart.

Comment: @Moab I did try that, but the disk is formatted as GPT and diskpart only lets you do that for MBR partitions.

Comment: I suggest a 3rd party backup tool like Macrium Reflect 8 Free.